# What happens in `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` and how does it relate to SQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate as an ORM framework. 
I have a bidirectional relationship that is implemented in Java as:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Parent")
    class Parent {
      ...
    
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true)
      private List<Child> child; 
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Child")
    class Child {
      ...
    
      @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
      private Parent parent; 
    }
```

Further the relational database table "Child" does have the following foreign key specification

```
fk_child_parent FOREIGN_KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

*Question 1:* Is it bad practice that the child class's foreign key is annotated with `cascade = CascadeType.All`? Based on my current understanding, I would assume that whenever I delete a child, I cascade the transaction and delete the parent as well. 
Since the parent might have more than one child, this will leave some orphan childs which will be removed due to the `orphanRemoval=true` option. Is this correct?

*Question 2:* In Java I already specify the cascade operation from the parent down to the children with `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, ...)`. Is the SQL line, or at least the `ON DELETE CASCADE` part of it, superfluous? 
Vice versa, if I have the SQL line `... ON DELETE CASCADE` that specifies the foreign key, can I skip the `@JoinColumn` or `@ManytoOne` annotations?

Please excuse if this is trivial question. I am new to databases / ORM, trying to wrap my head around the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CascadeType.ALL` is like using all of the `CascadeType` values i.e. `CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE` etc.

Every `CascadeType` refers to an operation on the `EntityManager`. If you do `entityManager.persist(parent)` then Hibernate will automatically do `entityManager.persist(child)` for every element in the list if you `CascadeType.PERSIST` is enabled. Same goes for other cascade types.